# How to use chai-as-promised with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, chai, chai-as-promised

I'm trying to use `chai-as-promised` package with TypeScript. First of all, the following code works well in simple JavaScript.

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
import * as chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const expect = chai.expect;

import * as sinon from 'sinon';

import { MyClass } from '.';

describe('Test my class', () => {
  let myClass: MyClass;

  beforeEach(() => {
    myClass = new MyClass();
   });

  it('Should render home', () => {
    const req = new RequestMock();
    const res = new ResponseMock();

    return expect(myClass.getHomePage(req, res)).to.be.fulfilled()
      .then((returnedValue) => {
        chai.expect(returnedValue).to.not.be.equal([]);
      });
  });
});
```

I have the following error with this code :

[image: enter image dedscription here]

... and it pointed to this :

```
interface PromisedTypeComparison {
    (type: string, message?: string): PromisedAssertion; // <<-- 
    instanceof: PromisedInstanceOf;
    instanceOf: PromisedInstanceOf;
}
```

I tested plenty of opportunity and it is the one where I am closest to the solution it seems to me.

I would like to use function of `chai-as-promise` like `fullfulled`, `rejected`... etc.

How can i make it ?

Comment: I do not understand yet how it should work but adding `""` as the first argument makes Typescript happy

Answer (score 11):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55855503/140707) is what you need:

> Add the [types for `chai-as-promised`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chai-as-promised) and that should take care of the TypeScript errors:
>
> `npm install --save-dev @types/chai-as-promised`

Worked for me. Before, I was getting "Property 'eventually' does not exist on type 'Assertion'."; after adding this everyone was happy :-)

I *did* have to change my `import` to a `require`.

Before:

```
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';
```

After:

```
import chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
```

Answer (score 9):

Just import the default of `chai-as-promised` and everything will work:

```
import * as chai from 'chai'    
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised'
chai.use(chaiAsPromised)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write this way

```
import { use as chaiUse } from 'chai';
import * as chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';

chaiUse(chaiAsPromised);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the '.eventually' or '.become' in the assertion.
Try rewriting it as

```
expect(myClass.getHomePage(req, res)).to.eventually.be.fulfilled;
```