# Chai Mocha test Promise Property 'eventually' does not exist

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to use Chai Promise test but it show an error 
I am using docker.

Here a simple function

```
            let funcPromise = (n) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
                    if(n=="a") {
                        resolve("success");
                    }else {
                        reject("Fail")
                    }
                })
            }
```

simple test

```
            import chai from 'chai';
            var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
            chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
            let expect = chai.expect;
            let assert = chai.assert;               

            it('connect: test promise', (done) => {
                let func = funcPromise("a");
                expect(func).to.eventually.equal("success"); // dont work
                expect(func).to.be.rejected; // dont work
            })
```

Error on terminal
`FileTest.spec.ts:43:25 - error TS2339: Property 'eventually' does not exist on type 'Assertion'.`

`storage/database/MongooseEngine.spec.ts:44:35 - error TS2339: Property 'rejected' does not exist on type 'Assertion'.`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The error is TypeScript complaining that it doesn't know about the additions that `chai-as-promised` makes to the `chai` assertions.

Add the [types for `chai-as-promised`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chai-as-promised) and that should take care of the TypeScript errors:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/chai-as-promised
```

You will also want to `await` any assertions made with `chai-as-promised`:

```
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const expect = chai.expect;

const funcPromise = (n) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (n === 'a') { resolve('success'); }
  else { reject('fail'); }
});

it('connect: test promise', async () => {
  await expect(funcPromise('a')).to.eventually.equal('success');  // Success!
  await expect(funcPromise('b')).to.be.rejected;  // Success!
});
```

Comment: Can i ask you something?
If i use done and done() like this `it( ... (done) => { ...other code... done() });` it throws `Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.` If i omit `done()` at the end it throws  `Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise` Do you know why? Or where i can read about it?

Comment: [This section](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) is a good resource.  That error means you are using `done` **and** returning a `Promise` (either by returning a `Promise` directly or by using an `async` test function).  `Mocha` throws that error to let you know that doing both isn't necessary...pick whichever makes your test easier (I usually use an `async` function and call `await` on any `Promises` during the test) @roll